# .NET Remoting SSL requirement

Tags: c#, ssl, https, remoting

I need to implement a remoting server in .NET C# and have the following requirements/restrictions for various reasons:

- Use .NET remoting and **NOT** WCF
- **NOT** hosted in IIS

There is no restriction on the version of .NET framework though (can be 3.5 if need be).

BUT: The server needs to be serving using **HTTPS**. I know I can do .NET remoting outside IIS with HTTP but how can I do HTTPS with the above requirements?

**UPDATE:** To clarify the requirements a bit further, I need to use SSL over any protocol for security reasons and port serve over port 80 for firewall reasons. I also need the protocol to be HTTPS so the deep inspection of packets on the firewall doesn't block the traffic. So using non-HTTP on port 80 is not quite the answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not WCF?

Comment: Why not just use a TCP channel? Or if on the same machine IPC.

Comment: This is a server for legacy clients using Remoting

Comment: Can you comment on how to implement SSL on top of that please?

Comment: Seems like others had the same issue: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=96465

Comment: No, you cant. SSL is on top of HTTP, not TCP. You will need some other form of message/transport security. Not sure if SSH would work.

Answer (score -1):

To leverage .Net remoting IIS is not mandatory, over config file (or even programmaticaly )  you can specify tcp:// to start listen/response over any IP port.
In this case you just need to resolve issue how server will available for clients.

- Create windows service
- create console with infinite loop to handle incoming request.

IIS in case of remoting just works as service to host your dll, that is why you can replace it.

Comment: The question is about SSL and security which your answer doesn't address.

Comment: You don't need IIS. That is why you can serialize your object by any protocol, just crypt stream with asymmetric RSA.

Comment: Dewfy, thanks for the reply. That's exactly what I'm looking for: How to put my SslStream into the remoting framework on both server and client.

Comment: In MSDN look at example with IpcChannel - NO IIS, just a IPSec. 
IPSec - standard feature to provide secured way of Tcp communication (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302429.aspx)